# Relay a port over internet to localhsot using .Net sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I have 2 applications

One is as server listening on 80 and port 4026

The second application application, connects to port 80 and port 4026

So both communicate over port 4026 to transport data to me.

I am trying to connect to first application locally through firefox on port 80 then have the second application connect to port 80 on google.com fetch website and bring it back to me.

so type localhost:80 should bring me google's web page

Here's a snippet of first applications code that's used to relay data. Relaydata1 and Relaydata2 are both threads running together.

```
public class serv
{

public static Socket socket1;
public static Socket socket2;

public static void Main()
{

        IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        IPAddress ipAd2 = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

        TcpListener myList1 = new TcpListener(ipAd, 80);
        TcpListener myList2 = new TcpListener(ipAd, 4026);


        myList2.Start();
        myList1.Start();



        Socket s2 = myList2.AcceptSocket();

        Console.WriteLine("Alright, someone connected from outside. " + s2.RemoteEndPoint + "   now open up the browser and connect to localhost port 80");

        Socket s1 = myList1.AcceptSocket();

        socket1 = s1;
        socket2 = s2;

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Relaydata1));
        t1.Start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Relaydata2));
        t2.Start();
}

private static void Relaydata1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[3072];
        socket1.Receive(b);
        socket2.Send(b);

    }
}

private static void Relaydata2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[3072];
        socket2.Receive(b);
        socket1.Send(b);
    }
}
}
```

Here's a snippet from second application. Again both routines run as a thread.

```
public class clnt
{
    static Stream stream1;
   static  Stream stream2;

    public static void Main()
    {
        TcpClient tcpclnt1 = new TcpClient();
        TcpClient tcpclnt2 = new TcpClient();

        tcpclnt1.Connect("127.0.0.1", 4026);  
        tcpclnt2.Connect("173.194.39.39", 80); 



        Stream stm1 = tcpclnt1.GetStream();
        Stream stm2 = tcpclnt1.GetStream();


        stream1 = stm1;
        stream2 = stm2;

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Relay1));
        t1.Start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Relay2));     
        t2.Start();



}

public static void Relay1()
{
    while (true)
    {

        byte[] bb = new byte[3072];
        stream1.Read(bb, 0, 3072);
        stream2.Write(bb, 0, bb.Length);
        stream2.Flush();

    }

}

public static void Relay2()
{

    while (true)
    {
        byte[] bb = new byte[3072];
        stream2.Read(bb, 0, 3072);
        stream1.Write(bb, 0, bb.Length);
        stream1.Flush();
    }


}
}
```

When I type localhost:80 into firefox, it asks me if I want to download an Octet stream and when accepting it gets stuck at 'starting'

I don't get why it isn't working I am basically forwarding data as-is from google to my server?

Comment: Are you trying to write a proxy?

Comment: Something like it, it's a fix for NAT, it allows a server behind a NAT to communicate with a user with no NAT.

Comment: You're not sending proper HTTP headers to the web browser.  When the browser opens a site, it expects an HTTP response and you're not giving one.  Why don't you print out exactly what data you're sending to your web browser.  Also, what's the point of having two processes?

Comment: How so? Everything that website responds with is supposedly immediately send back to other end?

Comment: Just print out what you're sending back.  Let's see if that's true.  (and obviously it's not, or the web browser wouldn't be complaining)

Comment: I just did some research and I discovered SSH tunnels and figured out reverse SSH tunnels will do the job.

Comment: boring.  Fix your code.  Learn 2 things today.

Comment: From what I understand, you are spawning 4 threads -- two in each section of code you posted.  When you should have a single thread and use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx